# Replace whole characters in a string with one character

Tags: c#, string, replace

How can I change a string to contain only 1 character? Example, how to change oldString to newString:

```
oldString = "Hello, world!";
newString = "-------------";

oldString = "Unwanted";
newString = "--------";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we all know the string is a collection of characters, so the constructor of the String class will help you to create a string by repeating a character `N` times. Here we can use that constructor for the creation. You can try like this:

```
string oldString = "Hello, world!";
string outStr = new String('-', oldString.Length);
Console.WriteLine(outStr);
```

Take a look into this [Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VGBrk7)

Comment: @slimjourney: Happy to help you as well